# custom spinner with text and icon has wrong images

Tags: android

What have I done wrong here? Think I need another set of eyeballs as I've been looking at it too long...

I have a custom spinner adapter that shows an image and text to select an attitude.  I'm pulling
both the string for the text and the icons from the resources I have. The text is correct, but the images are not just out of place, but sometimes completely crazy - not even in the set of images
I select.

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String[] attitude = new String[]{
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.happy),
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.sad),
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.angry),
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.difficult),
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.hurt),
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.confused),
            this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.stubborn)};


    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attitude_label);
    label.setText(attitude[position]);

    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.emoticon);

    switch (position) {
     case 0: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.happy);
         break;
     case 1: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
         break;
     case 2: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.angry);
         break;
     case 3: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.difficult);
         break;
     case 4: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hurt);
         break;
     case 5: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.confused);
         break;
     case 6: 
         icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.stubborn);
         break;
    }


    return row;
}
```

the picture below shows it all - the text is correct, but the images are not. Happy is clearly sad,
and what should be sad is another image resource I use for importing data. Angry and difficult and confused are fine, but hurt and stubborn are completely different resources, too.

What the biff?  I suspect I've done something trivial and just can't see it, so please kick me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello may be its helpful to you. pls try this.

public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView label;
        public ImageView icon;
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.label = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.attitude_label);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.emoticon);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

            holder.label.setText(attitude[position]);
            switch (position) {
 case 0: 
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.happy);
     break;
 case 1: 
     holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad);
     break;
 case 2: 
     holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.angry);
     break;
 case 3: 
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.difficult);
     break;
 case 4: 
     holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hurt);
     break;
 case 5: 
     holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.confused);
     break;
 case 6: 
     holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.stubborn);
     break;
}
 return vi;
```

}

Comment: I got it working....but things are just strange on Eclipse sometimes.  I added a Log.d("....") statement to track position, and attitude text, image, etc.    and things started magically working.  Nothing else in the code changed.   Very strange

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you needed to rebuild the project from scratch - in eclipse that means using project->clean?